# flutter In VS Code show error when I hit flutter run on my real device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging, gradle

when i hit flutter run on my real device it show me error below.my code was work ok at first but now it stuck.
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A307FN in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              5.6s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle. │
│                                                                               │
│ To get Java 11, update to the latest version of Android Studio on             │
│ https://developer.android.com/studio/install.                                 │
│                                                                               │
│ To check the Java version used by Flutter, run `flutter doctor -v`.           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall JAVA version 11 and install 1.8 version it worked for me hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Thank you very much, but someone on Facebook solved my problem. When I downloaded and installed the latest version of Android Studio, my problem was solved. Because I had my old Android Studio installed and Visual Studio wouldn't work without a newer version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show this files (C:\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle) content along with gradle.properties ?

**In your *project/android/app/build.gradle* there will be few lines like below:**

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

**if you want to use *java 11* , install java 11 and try adding these lines and replacing the above configuration:**

```
compileOptions {         
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11         
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11   
}  

kotlinOptions {         
     jvmTarget = '11'     
}
```

**and do vice-versa for otherwise**

Comment: thank you for the replay. your steps will take a long time but I also sent my error to the Facebook group they solved my problem by saying that install a new version of Android studio or update your current version. when I download the new version of Android studio it solved my problem.